# Getting error while linking two ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using a custom circular animation in my VC to segue to a new VC and it works fine and this is the code

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
    secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self
    secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
}
```

But when I use another button on the same VC to segue to some another VC, I get an error saying **Could not cast value of type 'I_Need.ReminderTableViewController' (0x1020e6e98) to 'I_Need.SecondViewController (0x1020e6a08).**

Comment: Why are you entering this segue code if you're going to a different type of controller?  Is the segue connected to the button directly or do you execute some action code when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `if let` instead of `let`, because your other VC is not of type `SecondViewController`:

```
if let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController{
    secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self
    secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
}
```